# Why is the input stream locked while Tomcat is working?

Tags: tomcat, servlets

I have a Tomcat app with a few servlets. The app runs an embedded java Applet and a GWT webpage.

The problem is my POST request to fetch some data from Tomcat is blocked while another request is being handled in another servlet request (different servlet).

This is my applet code to fetch the data:

```
Integer code =  new Integer(FETCH_IMAGE); 
Serializable objs[] =  { code, username, id.getID(), id.getSeriesID(), id.getStudyID()   };
//URLConnection con =  postObjects(servletUrl, objs);
System.out.println("---->POST image request start...");
URLConnection con =  servletHttpConnection.postObjects(objs);
System.out.println("---->POST image request end...");
System.out.println("---->ObjectInputStream start...");
ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream( con.getInputStream());
System.out.println("---->ObjectInputStream end...");

//Read the value as an Object
System.out.println("---->Read stream for image start...");
Object obj = in.readObject();
System.out.println("---->Read stream for image end...");
```

My Tomcat instance is doing some I/O and at the same time my applet executes the code above to try to fetch some data. I also dumped a log at the begining of "doPost" method and it doesn't even get there until request #1 is over. My applet is blocked at:

```
ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream( con.getInputStream());
```

Can I design around this issue? Or why is it blocked there, why does Tomcat fail to respond to my request #2 while #1 is working?

Comment: Tomcat, like any web container worth its salt, can handle many concurrent requests. If your server is only serving one request at a time, you've either configured it that way somehow, or your servlet classes are synchronizing on some common lock.

Comment: My server is serving concurrent request. The request #1 is doing I/O with a 3rd party server. Maybe tomcat cannot handle some other request reading a connection stream while some other socket in another thread is opened?

Comment: Are you sure that other servlet isn't holding a lock on something the second servlet needs?

Comment: I tried sending a request with http tool to the same blocked servlet and it responded with 500 error (I was expecting something I cannot supply with the tool). On my doPost method, I printed a log output telling me my request got at the post level in my tomcat server. But, the request I need to read from the connection (the one in the applet) doesn't even get to the doPost method meaning Tomcat is holding it off!